# OpenCart 1.5.6.4, change the menu color

Tags: html, css, opencart

OpenCart 1.5.6.4 default theme, I want replace background color of dropdown menu, which defined by backgroung image 'menu.png', with custom hex value.  CSS here:

```
#menu > ul > li > div {
    display: none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    background: url('../image/menu.png');
```

Should I just replace the last row in this CSS code with `background: #0404B4;`?
What is purpose of background property in second row: `background: #FFFFFF;`?

Comment: If the menu.png has any transparency in the image, the 2nd line `background` colour will show through.

Comment: I don't want image, so I only need `background:#0404B4;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if, You don't want image in background. just remove background image from css. You can use below css.

```
#menu > ul > li > div {
    display: none;
    background: #0404B4;;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```